# Half-lives. Need help designing an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Input:

```
x - how many days patient was taking a substance
y - how many miligrams per day
z - what's the half-life of the substance in hours
```

Output:

```
a - for how many hours substance will stay in patient's body
    (Let's assume that below y/200 threshold we say it's gone).
```

EDIT:
What I tried this far I know isn't correct. Here it goes:

```
public static int computeEliminationTime(int days, double dosage, int half_life) {
    double saturation = 0.0d;
    double threshold = dosage/200.0d;
    boolean isHeStillTakingMedicine = true;
    for (int hours = 0;; hours++) {
        if (isHeStillTakingMedicine) {
            if (hours % 24 == 0) {
                saturation += dosage;
                days--;
                if (days == 0){
                    isHeStillTakingMedicine = false;
                    hours=1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (hours % half_life == 0) {
            saturation /= 2.0d;
        }
        if (saturation < threshold) {
            return hours;
        }
    }
}
```

I know this approach is wrong because elimination of a substance is a continuous process it doesn't jast happen every half-life of hours. I researched a bit about [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) and I just don't know what to do with this monstrosity. My math skills are poor.

Comment: Have you researched about half-life problems, from a mathematical point of view? The solution to this problem is an differential equation.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: And please be explicit about `y` -- this quantity is consumed in a _single_ dose at the beginning of each day, right? Also, is `a` measured from the moment the _first_ dose was taken, or from the moment the _last_ dose was taken?

Comment: @Dilum y - single those at the beginning of each day, a - from last dose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I finally came up with:

```
public static int computeEliminationTime(int days, double dosage, int half_life) {
    double saturation = 0.0d;
    double threshold = dosage/200.0d;
    double degradationFactor = Math.pow(2, -1.0d/(double)half_life);
    boolean isHeStillTakingMedicine = true;
    for (int hours = 0;; hours++) {
        if (isHeStillTakingMedicine) {
            if (hours % 24 == 0) {
                saturation += dosage;
                days--;
                if (days == -1){
                    isHeStillTakingMedicine = false;
                    hours=0;
                }
            }
        }

        saturation = saturation * degradationFactor; 

        if (saturation < threshold) {
            return hours;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also made a small application that has a graph. `https://github.com/p-majewski/HalfLives`

Comment: I decided to accept my own answer because I was looking for an algorithm rather than a equation solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

First let's see how much the substance decays over a day. As over *z* hours the amount decreases by 1/2 times, then over 24 hours it would decrease by *q* = (1/2) <sup>24/*z*</sup> = 2 <sup>-24/*z*</sup> times.

Now let's see how much substance there will be after taking the last dose. After the first dose it's *T<sub>1</sub>* = *y*. And on day *n* + 1 the amount is *T*<sub>*n*+1</sub> = *T<sub>n</sub>* • *q* + *y*. And we need to find the amount of substance *T<sub>x</sub>* on day *x*.

If you try to write out the first few terms of this recurrence relation, you'll notice that this boils down to *T<sub>x</sub>* = *y* • *q* <sup>*x*-1</sup> + *y* • *q* <sup>*x*-2</sup> + ... + *y*. That's just a sum of a geometric progression. Thus, *T<sub>x</sub>* = *y* • (1 - *q* <sup>*x*</sup>) / (1 - *q*)

Now we have to find out how much time it takes for *T<sub>x</sub>* to decay to *y* / 200. That's **log**<sub>2</sub> (*T<sub>x</sub>* / (*y* / 200)) half-decay periods, which is equal to *z* • **log**<sub>2</sub> (*T<sub>x</sub>* / (*y* / 200)) hours.

So, if you substitute *T<sub>x</sub>*, the result will be *a* = *z* • **log**<sub>2</sub> (200 • (1 - *q* <sup>*x*</sup>) / (1 - *q*)) hours, where *q* = 2 <sup>-24/*z*</sup>

Comment: A bit too clever for me, all this logarithms and stuff. However your formula for q helped me a lot.

Comment: @VladK. It seems you are working in Java. In that case to calculate log2(x), you can use `Math.log(x) / Math.log(2)`, or use Guava library `DoubleMath.log2`. The whole formula is something like `double q = Math.pow(2, -24.0d/(double)half_life); double a = half_life * Math.log(200 * (1 - Math.pow(q, (double)days)) / (1 - q)) / Math.log(2)`. But test if it gives the correct results, I may have made some errors in my math.